# How to recognize Dual-Shock 4 controller with libhidapi0 library?

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth, cygwin, hid

I'm currently trying to complete a school lab from home with cygwin (can't use WSL due to Cygwin dependencies) and I keep getting the following error after running " ./ds4rd.exe -d 054C:09CC -D DS4_BT -t -a -g -b | ./lab5": `hid_open, try device enumeration and check Vendor ID and Product ID values.`. The following is from the help section of ds4rd.exe:

```
./ds4rd [-d DEVICE] [-D TYPE] [-j[lr]b[adt]tag]
-d - Device string, format is XXXX:XXXX
-D - Device Type: DS4_BT (DS4 Bluetooth) or DS4_USB (DS4 USB)
```

This is the link to the HID package: https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/libhidapi0.html

All Dependencies are installed and versions can be found in this picture:

[image]
[image]

I have tried every combination of -d and -D that I can think of and I'm at a loss. There are only a few combinations of possible DS4 product ID's and I've also tried all of those. Typically, this error would occur when the wire had a bad connection but this wouldn't be the case as it's connected via Bluetooth (I also tried doing this wired with no luck).

### Edit (1 & 2)

(1) I do not have the source code for "ds4rd.exe", (2) but because it works with the school computers and controllers, i think it has something to do with the configuration and handling of HID devices on my local computer